# when passing parameter to function Return null in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, stored-functions

This is my function

```
---Write procedure for retrive data----
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve_decrypt(
    custid  in NUMBER
)
RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
    decrypt_value sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
     open decrypt_value for Select custname,contactno, enc_dec.decrypt(creditcardno,password) as  
       creditcardno ,enc_dec.decrypt(income,password) as 
            income  from employees where custid=custid ;
    RETURN decrypt_value;
END;
/
```

I  called it like this : `SELECT retrieve_decrypt(5) FROM DUAL;` Then it return only {}.

[image]

but am I , hard code `custid=5` insted of `custid=custid`  .it will return result correctly. need some expert help to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you missing a : before the parameter? Ie. :custid

Comment: @jcruz are you mean like this  'custid=:custid' ,? when i put it , while compiling given error. 'ERror : 10/49     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'CUSTID')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name parameters as columns; if column name is `custid`, let parameter be `par_custid`. Otherwise, it will cause problems (as you can see).

In your example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve_decrypt (par_custid IN NUMBER)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
   decrypt_value  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN decrypt_value FOR
      SELECT custname,
             contactno,
             enc_dec.decrypt (creditcardno, password) AS creditcardno,
             enc_dec.decrypt (income, password) AS income
        FROM employees
       WHERE custid = par_custid;

   RETURN decrypt_value;
END;
/
```

Comment: Industry standard would normally be `p_custid` or `in_custid`, or of course there is `retrieve_decrypt.cust_id` :)

Comment: *A rose by any other name would smell as sweet*, @William (Shakespeare) :)